# Numerical mathematics, Lagrange interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I am trying to solve this problem, but I don't have any idea. Maybe it doesn't look at first sight that Lagrange interpolation can be used, but I found this problem in that chapter of Numerical methods, so I suppose that interpolation can be used.

The problem is:

Let $x_1 > x_2 > ... > x_n$ be natural numbers and let $P(x) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ be an arbitary polynomial with real coefficients. Prove that there exists $i\in {{1, 2, ..., n}}$ so that $|P(x_i)|\geq \frac{n!}{2^n}$.

Does anyone have idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be other restrictions or the statement is false. With $n=1,x_1=1, a=-1$ we have $P(x) = x-1$ and therefore $|P(x_1)|= |1 - 1|=0  \not \ge \frac{1}{2} = \frac{n!}{2^{n}}$

Comment: More generally: If you choose your $x_i \in \mathbb{N},$ the polynomial $P(x)=\prod (x-x_i)$ will have $P(x_i)=0,$ which is obviously **not** $\ge$ your bound.

Comment: Thanks @gammatester... I checked in book, and the text of the problem is the same as I wrote.. This is the problem from the book Numerical methods, the author is Desanka Radunovic.. So, I don't know if there is a mistake in the book... Thanks very much in any case..

Comment: There is a similar problem from the same book. Let $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n$ be random integer numbers so that is $x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n$. Prove that for each polynomial $P(x) = x^n + a_1 x^{n-1}+...+a_n$ is $ max_{0\leq i \leq n}|P(x_i)|\geq \frac{n!}{2^n}$. Can this problem be solved?

Comment: Do you use the book in its original language or is it a translation? I do not see any reasons why the $x_i$ should be natural numbers (or is it a hidden requirement $|x_i - x_k| \ge 1$)?  Anyway, because the values of a polynomial is zero at its roots the problem cannot be solved. **Note** that the bound has changed in your second example because here you have $n+1$ values $x_i!$

Comment: One big difference between the two problemy is that in the second case you have at least one value $x_i$ which **cannot** be a root of the polynomial, so this problem can make sense without an obvous contradiction!

Comment: I use the book in its original language, it is written in Serbian. Thanks very much, @gammatester..